# Check if part of string in a column table A exists in another column table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

Aim: Check if part of string in a column table A exists in another column table B

I want to check if any description of table B fits some string in group A (even it is in the middle or final of the string).

Tables:

Table A

```
 Id   Group              Present
-------------------------------
1    xyz dfdf             NULL
2    xyz aaa              NULL
3    34z df retrnkr       NULL
4    uu rtz win fd aa zz  NULL
5    uu rtz win sd er tr  NULL
-------------------------------
```

Table B

```
Id   Description  CreationDate
-----------------------------
1      xyz aaa     2018-05-14  
2      rtz win sd  2018-05-14
3      rtz win fd  2018-05-14 
4      rtr aaa     2018-05-14
5      rre         2018-05-14
6      gwe         2018-05-14
------------------------------
```

Final Result in Table A . Present is a boolean variable and it has bit as datatype. 1 if group present in table B, otherwise 0.

```
Id   Group              Present
-------------------------------
1    xyz dfdf             0
2    xyz aaa              1
3    34z df retrnkr       0
4    uu rtz win fd aa zz  1
5    uu rtz win sd er tr  1
-------------------------------
```

I have tried with

```
   update table A 
    set Present=1
    Where table A.[group] like '%' + (SELECT TOP 1 Description from Table B) + '%'
```

BUT IT only works to check if the first description exists in any string in table A... (there are strings in group with over 3000 characters). I need to run all descriptions in table B to see if any (only one!) fits each string in table A.

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `join`:

```
update a
  set Present = 1
  from a join
       b
       on a.[group] like '%' + b.description + '%';
```

Or, use `exists`:

```
update a
    set present = 1
    where exists (select 1 from b where a.[group] like '%' + b.description + '%');
```

Because of the wildcards in the `like` pattern, these will not be efficient queries and they are hard to optimize.

Comment: Why not use `charindex`? Wouldn't it affect efficiency positively?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn . . . `like` is standard SQL.  I generally prefer SQL standards over ad-hoc, database-specific functions.